# I removed my video card, and my login screen vanished, too

Tags: 11.04, video, login

I removed my Nvidia graphics card, plugged my monitor into my motherboard's DVI port.

I then turned the computer on, saw the BIOS settings, saw the distinctive plain-purple screen, then... a black screen. Nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> restarts the computer, and the same process happens. If I hit the power button, some shutdown text appears on the screen very quickly (I believe it includes the words "Ubuntu"), and then the computer turns off.

How can I make the login screen show up? I no longer have the graphics card. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Did you install proprietary drivers for your Nvidia card? What make is your onboard graphics adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you hold down the left shift key on boot and use "Recovery Mode"?

If so drop to a root shell and run:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```